# Different scopes within an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I need his code to work with iframes in IE8+
I have the html code in a string, but scripts with and without src-s are in a different scope in IE8.
So the 1. file is Jquery, but the 4. file runs on an error: "jQuery is not defined". 
For example:

```
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

The significant part of my code:

```
    var iframe = document.getElementById('my_iframe')

    if (frame == null) {
        return;
    }

    iframe.style.display = 'block';
    var doc = null;

    if (iframe.contentDocument)
        doc = iframe.contentDocument;
    //IE8!
    else if (iframe.contentWindow)
        doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;

    if (doc === null) {
        return;
    }

    // the content variable has the html in a string, here I get the script elements out of this string
    //...

    doc.open();
    doc.write(content);

    if (typeof doc.charset != 'undefined') {
        try {
            doc.charset = "utf-8"
        } catch (exception) {}
    }

// appending script to the iframe
var loadScript = function(srcArray) {
    if (srcArray.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    var src = '';
    // test if the script has an scr attribute
    if (/<\s*script[^>]+src\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"[^>]*>\s*<\/script[^>]*>/gi.test(srcArray[0])) {
        var srcIndex = srcArray[0].indexOf('src="') +5;
        var lastI = srcArray[0].indexOf('"', srcIndex)

        for (var i = srcIndex; i < lastI; i++) {
            src += srcArray[0][i]
        }
    //no src attribute
    } else {
        var stripedScript = srcArray[0];
        stripedScript = stripedScript.replace(/<\s*script[^>]*>/gi, '');
        stripedScript = stripedScript.replace('</script>', '');

        var newScript = doc.createElement('script');
        newScript.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        newScript.setAttribute("charset", 'utf8');
        newScript.text = stripedScript;

        doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);

        srcArray.shift();
        loadScript(srcArray);
        return;
    }

    // has scr attribute

    var newScript = doc.createElement('script');
    newScript.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    newScript.setAttribute("charset", 'utf8');
    newScript.setAttribute("src", src);
    var head = doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

    newScript.onload = newScript.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (!this.readyState || this.readyState === "loaded" || this.readyState === "complete") {

            // Handle memory leak in IE
            newScript.onload = newScript.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (newScript.parentNode) {
                head.removeChild(newScript);
            }

            srcArray.shift();
            loadScript(srcArray);
        }
    };

    head.appendChild(newScript);
};

// the scripts array containts the script elements with and without src attribute
loadScript(scripts);

doc.close();
```

Comment: You may need to run `$(function(){ /* put code here */})` in each external script src and see what happens.

Comment: I can't do that, since I have many of them and I can't rewrite codes like bootstrap.
Or do you mean inside my code? But first I don't have jQuery there.